# Taking user input with getline() and comparing to another string in a while loop

Tags: c

I am using the code below to take in user input and then compare it with the string `exit` so that users can exit out of a game by typing that into the command line. However it doesn't work unless I use `*buffer` in the comparison with `exit`. It does that because it points to the first letter in `exit`. The problem is that means any word starting with `e` will cause my while loop to exit.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int input( char *s, int length);

int main(){

    char *buffer;
    size_t bufsize = 32;
    size_t characters;

    do{
        buffer = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));

        if(buffer == NULL){
            perror("Unable to allocate buffer");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Enter a command: ");
        characters = getline(&buffer, &bufsize, stdin);
        printf("%zu characters were read.\n", characters);
        printf("You typed: '%s' \n",buffer);

    }while(buffer != "exit");
}
```

Comment: `buffer != "exit"` -> `(strcmp(buffer, "exit"))`. Please use a search engine to look up 1. why you should now cast the return value of `malloc()` 2. How to declare the `main()` function properly.

Comment: `getline()` stores the newline in the buffer, so you'll need to either include that in your comparison string, or chomp it off.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Dolda2000

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly compare strings in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

`while(buffer != "exit");`

with

`while(strcmpi(buffer, "exit"));`

In C, you can't check logical equality of string with == or != operators. You need to use functions like '`strcmp`' or `strcmpi`.

Comment: Note: `strcmpi()` is not a standard C function.

Comment: @chux, yes, that's why I mentioned both strcmp and strcmpi as options. In case `strcmpi` is not available in OP's C library, he can use `strcmp`. Worth noting nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

`buffer != "exit"` -> `(strcmp(buffer, "exit\n"))`

Answer (score 0):

If you compare strings with `==`, you are only comparing the base address of the strings, and not the actual contents of the strings. Use [`strcmp`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) from `<string.h>` to compare strings. You while statement should be this instead:

```
while (strcmp(buffer, "exit"));
```

**Note:** You should also compile with `-Wall -Wextra` in your code, and you would have seen some warnings with using `==` to compare strings.

However, since [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html) appends a `\n` at the end of the buffer, similarily to [`fgets`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm), you might need to remove this `\n` character. This would allow your code to work as intended. Otherwise, your code is actually doing this:

```
while (strcmp("exit\n", "exit"));
```

which will not allow the loop to terminate when `"exit"` is found, as `strcmp()` only returns `0` for equal strings.

You also need to check errors with `getline()`, as it returns `-1` on failure to read a line. Their is also no need to allocate memory with `malloc()` in this case, as `getline()` stores the address of the buffer within `*buffer`. The function `getline()` basically allocates memory for you, so doing it yourself in this case would be redundant. Having said this, you do need to `free()`this buffer at some point. See this [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html) for more details.

Considering these points, you can construct your code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void ){
    char *buffer = NULL;
    size_t buffsize;
    ssize_t read = 0;
    const char *exits = "exit";

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter a command: ");

        read = getline(&buffer, &buffsize, stdin);
        if (read == -1) {
            printf("Failure found from getline()\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (read > 0 && buffer[read-1] == '\n') {
            buffer[read-1] = '\0';
        }

        if (!*buffer || strcmp(buffer, exits) == 0) {
            break;
        }

        printf("%zu characters were read.\n", read);
        printf("You typed: '%s' \n", buffer);

        free(buffer);
        buffer = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```